# Access $auth0 object in the Vue router

Tags: typescript, vue.js, authentication, auth0

I have followed [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/auth0-vue-typescript-quickstart-docs/) tutorial to integrate Auth0 into my Vue Typescript SPA. I am having issues accessing the `$auth` object in the Vue router. I need to be able to check if the user is authenticated in order to re-route them to the correct page.

Here is what I have:

in `auth/auth.ts`:

```
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue'
import { VueAuth, Auth0Options, RedirectCallback } from './VueAuth'

type Auth0PluginOptions = {
  onRedirectCallback: RedirectCallback,
  redirectUri: string,
  domain: string,
  clientId: string,
  audience?: string,
  [key: string]: string | RedirectCallback | undefined
}

/** Define a default action to perform after authentication */
const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = (appState) =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname)

let instance: VueAuth

/** Returns the current instance of the SDK */
export const getInstance = () => instance

/** Creates an instance of the Auth0 SDK. If one has already been created, it returns that instance */
export const useAuth0 = ({
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  redirectUri = window.location.origin,
  ...options
}) => {
  if (instance) return instance

  // The 'instance' is simply a Vue object
  instance = new VueAuth()
  instance.init(onRedirectCallback, redirectUri, options as Auth0Options) 

  return instance
}

// Create a simple Vue plugin to expose the wrapper object throughout the application

export const Auth0Plugin = {
  install (Vue: VueConstructor, options: Auth0PluginOptions) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = useAuth0(options)
  }
}
```

in `auth/authGuard.ts`:

```
import { getInstance } from './auth'
import { NavigationGuard } from 'vue-router'

export const authGuard: NavigationGuard = (to, from, next) => {
  const authService = getInstance()

  const fn = () => {
    // Unwatch loading
    unwatch && unwatch()
    
    // If the user is authenticated, continue with the route
    if (authService.isAuthenticated) {
      return next()
    }

    // Otherwise, log in
    authService.loginWithRedirect({ appState: { targetUrl: to.fullPath } })
  }

  // If loading has already finished, check our auth state using `fn()`
  if (!authService.loading) {
    return fn()
  }

  // Watch for the loading property to change before we check isAuthenticated
  const unwatch = authService.$watch('loading', (loading: boolean) => {
    if (loading === false) {
      return fn()
    }
  })
}
```

in `auth/VueAuth.ts`:

```
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import createAuth0Client, { PopupLoginOptions, Auth0Client, RedirectLoginOptions, GetIdTokenClaimsOptions, GetTokenSilentlyOptions, GetTokenWithPopupOptions, LogoutOptions } from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js'
import { User } from './User'

export type Auth0Options = {
  domain: string
  clientId: string
  audience?: string
  [key: string]: string | undefined
}

export type RedirectCallback = (appState) => void


@Component({})
export class VueAuth extends Vue {
  loading = true
  isAuthenticated? = false
  user?: User
  auth0Client?: Auth0Client
  popupOpen = false
  error?: Error

  async getUser () {
    return new User(await this.auth0Client?.getUser())
  }

  /** Authenticates the user using a popup window */
  async loginWithPopup (o: PopupLoginOptions) {
    this.popupOpen = true

    try {
      await this.auth0Client?.loginWithPopup(o)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      this.error = e
    } finally {
      this.popupOpen = false
    }

    this.user = await this.getUser()
    this.isAuthenticated = true
  }

  /** Authenticates the user using the redirect method */
  loginWithRedirect (o: RedirectLoginOptions) {
    console.log(this.auth0Client)
    return this.auth0Client?.loginWithRedirect(o)
  }

  /** Returns all the claims present in the ID token */
  getIdTokenClaims (o: GetIdTokenClaimsOptions) {
    return this.auth0Client?.getIdTokenClaims(o)
  }

  /** Returns the access token. If the token is invalid or missing, a new one is retrieved */
  getTokenSilently (o: GetTokenSilentlyOptions) {
    return this.auth0Client?.getTokenSilently(o)
  }

  /** Gets the access token using a popup window */
  getTokenWithPopup (o: GetTokenWithPopupOptions) {
    return this.auth0Client?.getTokenWithPopup(o)
  }

  /** Logs the user out and removes their session on the authorization server */
  logout (o: LogoutOptions) {
    return this.auth0Client?.logout(o)
  }

  /** Use this lifecycle method to instantiate the SDK client */
  async init (onRedirectCallback: RedirectCallback, redirectUri: string, auth0Options: Auth0Options) {
    // Create a new instance of the SDK client using members of the given options object
    this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
      domain: auth0Options.domain,
      client_id: auth0Options.clientId, // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
      audience: auth0Options.audience,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
    })

    try {
      // If the user is returning to the app after authentication..
      if (
        window.location.search.includes('error=') ||
        (window.location.search.includes('code=') && window.location.search.includes('state='))
      ) {
        // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
        const { appState } = await this.auth0Client?.handleRedirectCallback() ?? { appState: undefined }

        // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
        // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
        onRedirectCallback(appState)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      this.error = e
    } finally {
      // Initialize our internal authentication state when the page is reloaded
      this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth0Client?.isAuthenticated()
      let tempAuthentication = await this.returnIsAuthenticated();
      this.user = await this.getUser()
      this.loading = false
      console.log('isAuthenticated: ', this.isAuthenticated)
      console.log('tempAuthentication: ', tempAuthentication)
    }
  }

  async returnIsAuthenticated (){
    return await this.auth0Client?.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

and in my `router/index.ts`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Login from "@/views/Login.vue";
import AuthProfile from "../views/AuthProfile.vue";
import { authGuard } from "../auth/authGuard";
import { getInstance } from "../auth";
import store from "@/data-store/index";
import { RouteMeta } from "@/types";

Vue.use(Router);
let auth0Code = null;
let auth0State = null;

const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home"
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: "/authprofile",
      name: "authprofile",
      component: AuthProfile,
      beforeEnter: authGuard
    }
  ]
});
export default router;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const authService = getInstance();
  console.log(authService.isAuthenticated);
  if (!authService.isAuthenticated) {
    console.log("isAuthenticated: ", authService.isAuthenticated);
    if (to.fullPath.includes("code")) {
      console.log("redirect path: ", next);
      auth0Code = to.query.code;
      console.log("includes code: ", auth0Code);
      auth0State = to.query.state;
      console.log("includes state: ", auth0State);
    }
    if (to.path === "/login" || to.path.includes("/forgot-password")) {
      return next();
    } else {
      return next({
        path: "/login",
        query: to.path.includes("logout") ? null : { from: to.fullPath }
      });
    }
  }
  // If the user tries to go to the login route manually and they
  // are already logged in, don't allow it.
  if (authService.isAuthenticated && to.path === "/login") {
    return next({ path: "/" });
  }

  // Redirect to the auth0 profile page when authenticated
  if (to.fullPath === "/" && authService.isAuthenticated) {
    return next({ path: "/authprofile" });
  }
});
```

After authenticating the user with Auth0, I want to redirect them to the `/authprofile` page. However, the `authService.isAuthenticated` is always false. It seems like I am not accessing the `$auth0` object correctly.

Any pointers? I have been banging my head against the wall.

Comment: with the hint of always being always false, have you tried this guide? https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-vue-user-authentication/
Wait until it is no longer loading. `authService.$watch('isLoading', (isLoading) => {`